# Dimensional analysis of sums

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dimensional-analysis

Quick question: What is the dimension of the following fraction

($\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i b_i )/ \sum_{i}^{n}a_i$

where

$a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ are in kg

and $b_1,b_2,...,b_n$ are in Newton?

Comment: This seems straightforward. Can you give a bit more detail to explain what aspect of it is causing you problems?

Comment: Sure. Is it possible to just cancel the kg expressions when they are in sums? So that [kg*N/kg] = [N]?

Comment: What is the unit for the mass of a system of two 1kg masses ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If we take your expression:

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i b_i }{\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i} $$

we can write the mass $a_i$ as a dimensionless number $A_i$ times a mass of 1kg to get:

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(A_i \, 1kg) b_i }{\sum_{i=1}^{n}(A_i \, 1kg)} $$

And because the $1kg$ is just a constant we can take it outside the sum:

$$ \frac{1kg\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i b_i }{1kg\,\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i} $$

And the $1kg$ then cancels to leave just:

$$ \frac{\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i b_i }{\sum_{i=1}^{n}A_i} $$

And since $A_i$ is dimensionless the dimensions of the result are just due to $b_i$. So yes you can cancel the $kg$.